# file reading in debian;

Tags: c++, file, debian

I need to read config file, containing key value pairs.
File contains several strings like this:

key1=value1
key2=value2
keyN=valueN

***//terminate

```
class CFG
{
   public:

      static void Init(char* path_);
      static string Param(string name_);
      static string PrintAll();

   private:

      static void GetPathEXE(string path_);
      static void ParseConfigFile();
      static map<string, string> mapData;
};

void CFG::ParseConfigFile()
{
   ifstream file;
   file.open(Param("HomePath") + Param("Slash") + "ConfigMS.cfg");
   if (file.is_open())
   {
      string file_line;
      cmatch results;
      regex reg3("(.*)=(.*)", std::regex_constants::ECMAScript);
      std::cout<<"Parsing cfg file"<<endl;
      while (getline(file, file_line) && (file_line.substr(0, 3) != "***"))
      {
         std::cout<<file_line<<endl;
         std::regex_match(file_line.c_str(), results, reg3);
         mapData.insert(std::pair<string,string>(results.str(1),results.str(2) ));
         mapData[string(results.str(1))] =string( results.str(2));
         std::cout<<"key: "<<results.str(1)<<" val: "<<results.str(2)<<endl;

      }
      //mapData["OuterIP"] = "10.77.1.68";
      std::cout<<"Config loaded\n";
      for (auto it : mapData)
      {
         std::cout<<it.first<<"="<<it.second<<endl;
      }

      if (Param("OuterIP") == "") mapData["Error"] = "IP for receiving messages not set in *.cfg file.\n";
      //else if (data["sipName"] == "") error = "sipName for receiving messages not set in *.cfg file.\n";
   }
   else { mapData["Error"] = "Could not open *.cfg file. Check its existance or name. Name Must \"be ConfigMS.cfg\".\n"; }
   if (Param("RTPPort") == Param("MGCPPort"))
   {
      mapData["Error"] = "RTP port is same as MGCP port. Please change one of them.\n";
   }
   if (Param("Error") != "")
   {
      cout << "\n" + Param("Error");
      //system("pause");
      exit(-1);
   }

}
string CFG::Param(string name_)
{

   return mapData[name_];
}
```

If I rely on file input i have [OuterIP,10.77.1.68] key value pair in my map, but function CFG::Param("OuterIP") returns empty string; And I have no idea how to work around this problem;

Comment: Use [boost property tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/property_tree.html)

Comment: What happens if in file there are no `RTPPort` and `MGCPPort` entires ? This line `if (Param("RTPPort") == Param("MGCPPort"))` returns true because two empty strings are equal. Then next `if` is executed and your program is aborted by `exit` function.

Comment: I have Init() function, which sets some defaults, these line just checks changes, which may appear after config file parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I've compiled you code with small modifications and it works.
rafix07 told us the program exits if there is no MGCPort and RTPPort values, and he is right, but you told explicitly that the function returns an empty string. Are you sure there isn't another empty OuterIP parameter in the file?

BTW my modifications are removing the path, reading just the file and commenting out the `exit(-1)` thing. (As well as adding a main function.)

```
#include <regex>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class CFG
{
   public:

      static void Init(char* path_);
      static string Param(string name_);
      static void ParseConfigFile();

   private:

      static void GetPathEXE(string path_);
      static map<string, string> mapData;
};

void CFG::ParseConfigFile()
{
   ifstream file;
   file.open("ConfigMS.cfg");

   if (file.is_open())
   {
      string file_line;
      cmatch results;
      regex reg3("(.*)=(.*)", std::regex_constants::ECMAScript);
      std::cout<<"Parsing cfg file"<<endl;
      while (getline(file, file_line) && (file_line.substr(0, 3) != "***"))
      {
         std::cout<<file_line<<endl;
         std::regex_match(file_line.c_str(), results, reg3);
         mapData.insert(std::pair<string,string>(results.str(1),results.str(2) ));
         mapData[string(results.str(1))] =string( results.str(2));
         std::cout<<"key: "<<results.str(1)<<" val: "<<results.str(2)<<endl;

      }
      //mapData["OuterIP"] = "10.77.1.68";
      std::cout<<"Config loaded\n";
      for (auto it : mapData)
      {
         std::cout<<it.first<<"="<<it.second<<endl;
      }

      if (Param("OuterIP") == "") mapData["Error"] = "IP for receiving messages not set in *.cfg file.\n";
      //else if (data["sipName"] == "") error = "sipName for receiving messages not set in *.cfg file.\n";
   }
   else { mapData["Error"] = "Could not open *.cfg file. Check its existance or name. Name Must \"be ConfigMS.cfg\".\n"; }
   if (Param("RTPPort") == Param("MGCPPort"))
   {
      mapData["Error"] = "RTP port is same as MGCP port. Please change one of them.\n";
   }
   if (Param("Error") != "")
   {
      cout << "\n" + Param("Error");
      //system("pause");
      //exit(-1);
   }

}
string CFG::Param(string name_)
{

   return mapData[name_];
}

map<string, string> CFG::mapData;

int main ()
{
    CFG::ParseConfigFile ();


    cout << "Param: " << CFG::Param("OuterIP") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the program as I've compiled with:

```
g++ main.cc -o regex -std=c++11
```

This is the configuration file:

```
OuterIP=10.0.0.1
```

And these are the results:

```
Parsing cfg file

key:  val: 

key:  val: 
OuterIP=10.0.0.1
key: OuterIP val: 10.0.0.1
Config loaded
=
OuterIP=10.0.0.1

RTP port is same as MGCP port. Please change one of them.
Param: 10.0.0.1
```

As you can see, the last line is the cout in main.

So your code works. You have to remove the `exit(-1)` from the class. It doesn't have sense anyway.

Comment: I have only 2 strings in test file, and their keys are not equal (OuterIP and MediaPath)